# Pasar una matriz como parámetro a un procedimiento almacenado en mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench

Tengo dos array uno con 180 registros que es un consolidado y otra matriz que es detalle con un universo de 6 mil registros (entendiendo que esto puede variar dependiendo del archivo), debo hacer transacciones por cada registro del consolidado debo recorrer el detalle según hay match o no.

mi tema es que la aplicacion se sobre carga y se cae por lo que quiero llevar la carga a un SP en mysql ya que es un servidor dedicado no hay problema de performance.

e trabajado SP en sqlserver pero no mucho en mysql asi que no se si se pueden pasar array como variables y si se puede nose como abordarlo,

Es por eso que recurro a sus conocimientos

Comment: ¿Le quieres pasar arrays al SP? Yo creo que sería mejor que dentro del SP consultes lo que necesites y ahí recorras y pongas la transacción por registro, si ya lo vas a hacer en SP haz el proceso completo no una parte y pretendas enviarle muchos datos desde fuera

Comment: El array como tal no lo puedes pasar, pero puedes pasar un String , separado por comas

Comment: @shop350 lo que pasa es que los datos vienen desde un archivo externo que le hago tratamiento hasta ese punto no eh realizado ninguna transaccion en la bd//

Comment: @IvanFontalvo muchas gracias lo intentare no se me habia ocurrido hacerlo de esa manera, si me resulta publicare la respuesta, Saludos